# Error When Mounting ADLS Gen 2 abfss from Databricks: Error IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported Azure Scheme: abfss

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I have modified some code kindly provided by @Bhagyashree in an attempt to mount abfss on ADLS Gen 2

```
container_name = "root"
storage_account = "mystorageaccount"
key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

url = "abfss://" + container_name + "@" + storage_account + ".dfs.core.windows.net/"
config = "fs.azure.account.key." + storage_account + ".blob.core.windows.net"

mount_folder = "/mnt/lake"
mounted_list = dbutils.fs.mounts()

mounted_exist = False
for item in mounted_list:
  if mount_folder in item[0]:
    mounted_exist = True
    break

  if not mounted_exist:
    dbutils.fs.mount(source = url, mount_point = mount_folder, extra_configs = {config : key})
```

The goal is achieve a mount that looks like the following

[image]

But I get the error

```
IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported Azure Scheme: abfss
```

Any thoughts on why I'm getting the error?

Answer (score 7):

- When I tried the same code for mounting azure data lake storage using account key, I got the same error.

[image]

- Mounting `abfss` might require `OAuth` authentication and hence mounting abfss using account key is throwing an error. Modifying the code as shown below, I was able to mount and list its contents:

```
container_name = "data"
storage_account = "datalk230523"
key = "<account_key>"

url = "wasbs://" + container_name + "@" + storage_account + ".blob.core.windows.net/"
config = "fs.azure.account.key." + storage_account + ".blob.core.windows.net"

mount_folder = "/mnt/repro"
dbutils.fs.mount(source = url, mount_point = mount_folder, extra_configs = {config : key})
```

[image]

- Using `dbutils.fs.ls`, I was able to list the contents successfully. The following is an output image for reference:

[image]

**NOTE:** You need to modify the loop logic after the mount as it is iterating for the second time as well and the mounted list does not have the latest mount information.

Comment: Hi @Saideep, thanks for reaching out. Going to try your suggestion now. I will let you know. However, are you saying that you were able to mount abfss ?

Comment: Hi, @Saideep, your code isn't mounting ADLS Gen 2, ie. abfss

Comment: `datalk230523` is an adls account. However, with account key and using wasbs protocol instead, I was able to mount it. I am not sure about the differences however

Comment: Hey @Patterson, the storage account that I used is an adls account itself. This is the image of the storage accocunt: https://i.imgur.com/IWRgRGB.png . Are you getting any error?

Comment: oh, I see. I was just curious why you're not seeing abfss, instead of wasbs?

Comment: abfss protocol might require the usage of `Oauth` authentication i.e., via service principal. I tried using wasbs with the same data lake storage gen2 instead and was able to mount.

Comment: ok, it's working. But I wonder why we can't see abfss.

Comment: You have just answered my last question :-) Thank you @Saideep

Comment: I am also receiving the same error. However, I have used "Oauth" authentication. Still receiving the same error. I want to avoid "wasbs". Because I want to use data lake gen2 i.e. abfss. Any solution here

Answer (score 1):

ABFSS wasn't working for me. According to some answers here it could be because I am using the Azure Storage Connection Key to authenticate (not the Service Principal + RBAC).
Changing the driver to wasbs worked but make sure you change the Spark config accordingly. This function might help you save some time. Note that I wasn't able to test it using the oauth authentication due to the limits I have in my environment:

```
def mount_adls(storage_account_name, container_name, auth_type):   
  assert auth_type in ["oauth", "key"], "auth_type must be either 'oauth' or 'key'"
  account_key = dbutils.secrets.get(scope="my_keys", key="my_storage_account_key")
  
  if auth_type == "oauth":
    source = f"abfss://{container_name}@{storage_account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net/"
    extra_configs = {f"fs.azure.account.key.{storage_account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net":account_key}  
  else:
    source = f"wasbs://{container_name}@{storage_account_name}.blob.core.windows.net"
    extra_configs = {f"fs.azure.account.key.{storage_account_name}.blob.core.windows.net": f"{account_key}"}    

  try: 
    dbutils.fs.mount(
        source = source,
        mount_point = f"/mnt/{container_name}",
        extra_configs = extra_configs
    )
    print("Storage mounted successfully.")
  except Exception as e:
      if "already mounted" in str(e):
          print("Storage is already mounted.")
      else:
          print(f"Error mounting storage: {e}")

mount_adls('my_storage_account', 'my_container', auth_type='key')
```